# Proving a noninvertible function is onto?

Tags: functions

How do I prove that $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R, \;f(x) = x^3 - 3x$ is onto?  Is it always necessary to find an inverse function?  I guess there is some way to restrict such a function's domain so it's outside the overlapping parts $x < -\sqrt{3}$ or $x \ge \sqrt{3}$, but how do I express this mathematically?  Or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: What is your domain? codomain? $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, it's $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The proof is essentially: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$. Since $f$ is continuous the intermediate value theorem guarantees the range is $(-\infty,\infty)$ (everything). Thus onto.

Comment: Oh, I like this one even better!  Thanks!

Comment: I think the takeaway here is: whenever you see a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, don't forget about calculus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to prove that for any real number $b$, there is an $x$ such that $x^3-3x=b$.
If $x$ is large enough negative, $x^3-3x$ is for sure $<b$.  So there is a number $L$ such that $L^3-3L<b$.

If $x$ is large enough positive, then $x^3-3x>b$. So there is a number $M>L$ such that $M^3-3M>b$.

Since the function $x^3-3x$ is continuous, by the *Intermediate Value Theorem*, there is an $x$ such that $L<x<M$ and $x^3-3x=b$.

Or else let $f(x)=x^3-3x-b$. By what was written above, there is an $L$ such that $f(L)<0$, and there is an $M>L$ such that $f(M)>0$. So (again by the Intermediate Value Theorem) there is an $x$ between $L$ and $M$ such that $f(x)=0$, maning that $x^3-3x=b$.  More informally, the function is negative somewhere, positive somewhere, so the graph of $y=f(x)$ must cross the $x$-axis, so by continuity $f(x)$ must be $0$ somewhere.

**Comment:** There is an old ($16$-th century) complicated but explicit formula, called the *Cardano Formula*, for the roots of a cubic. Unfortunately, at least for some values of $b$ (those for which $f(x)$ has $3$ distinct real roots) the formula is very difficult to work with.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Gregory: Good. I was afraid that you might not have met the Intermediate Value Theorem. If it is not entirely familiar, you can find information on Wikipedia, or in almost any calculus book.

Comment: Yeah, a few days ago, in fact, I spent quite a bit of time trying to derive Cardano's cubic formula.  It's amazing to me how much complexity there is in these little polynomials that seem so simple.

Comment: I've taken tons of calculus, I'm just slow, I guess.  My brain's not working this morning.

Comment: @Matt Gregory: About Cardano's formula, there is a further complication. When there are $3$ real roots (the *casus irreducibilis*) then cube roots of non-real numbers are unavoidable, even though the ultimate answers are real!

Comment: Actually, I was trying to figure out how to "complete the cube", but I guess if Cardano's formula requires complex numbers, then completing the cube would require them, too.  That's really odd!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to restrict the domain. You need only show that for any $y$ in the range of your function (I'll assume it's $\Bbb R$), that the equation
$$
f(x)=y
$$
has a solution. That, is you need to show that any element in the range is actually an output value of the function.

Here, you'd fix $y\in\Bbb R$ and  consider the equation
$$
x^3-3x=y.
$$
Or
$$
x^3-3x-y=0.
$$
Since this is a polynomial equation of degree 3, it does have a real solution
(by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra; you could also take a Calculus approach to show this).
If you call this solution $a_y$, then $f(a_y)=y$. Thus $f$ is onto.